# How to use tf.layers.conv2d to train a autoencoder with tied weights

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder

If I want to train an autoencoder with tied weights (encoder and decoder has same weight parameters), how to use `tf.layers.conv2d` to do that correctly?

I cannot just simply share variables between corresponding `conv2d` layers of encoder and decoder, because the weights of decoder is the transpose of that of encoder.

Maybe tied weights are barely used nowadays, but I am just curious.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/pkmital/tensorflow_tutorials/blob/master/python/09_convolutional_autoencoder.py) is a tutorial of a convolutional autoencoder using shared weights

Answer (score 1):

Use [`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) (and [`tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose) correspondingly). It's a low-level function that accepts the `kernel` variable as an argument.

```py
kernel = tf.get_variable('kernel', [5, 5, 1, 32])
...
encoder_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
...
decoder_conv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(images, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```